# Expandable layout в fragment

Tags: android

Проблема такая я нашёл как можно сделать Expandable layout а если точнее то https://github.com/andyxialm/ExpandableLayout так вот там оно сделано в Activity а как его сделать в Fragment? Когда я тот же код добавляю в java Fragment то он ругается на: 
"View switcher1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.switcher_1_test);"
А в ошибке пишет это "error: unreachable statement View switcher1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.switcher_1_test);"

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

    private ExpandableLayout mExpandableLayout1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_tasks_p, container, false);

        View switcher1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.switcher_1_test);
        mExpandableLayout1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout_1_test);
        mExpandableLayout1.setSwitcher(switcher1);
        mExpandableLayout1.setExpandInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        mExpandableLayout1.setCollapseInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        mExpandableLayout1.setExpandDuration(800);
        mExpandableLayout1.setCollapseDuration(400);

        mExpandableLayout1.setOnStateChangedListener(new ExpandableLayout.OnStateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPreExpand() {
                Log.d("ExpandableLayout", "onPreExpand");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreCollapse() {
                Log.d("ExpandableLayout", "onPreCollapse");
            }

            @Override
            public void onExpanded() {
                Log.d("ExpandableLayout", "onExpanded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCollapsed() {
                Log.d("ExpandableLayout", "onCollapsed");
            }
        });
        getView().findViewById(R.id.btnTitle_1_test).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mExpandableLayout1.toggle();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: ну добавлять что-то после return не очень хорошая идея... сделайте переопределение onViewCreated и перенесите туда весь код, что после return

Comment: @IR42 Я перенёс весь код после return и переименовал onCreateView в onViewCreated и теперь при запуске ничего не отображается

Comment: я не говорил переименовывать, должны быть оба метода, в `onCreateView` будет только `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_tasks_p, container, false);` , в onViewCreated всё остальное

Comment: @IR42 Заработало)) спасибо большое. Я могу тебе как-нибудь лайк поставить или что-то тип того?